# Temperament intonation

Tags: intonation, temperament

In my preview questions I forgot to excuse me for my bad Emglish. I am Bulgarian and I speak French much better than English. I would precise anything in my question about a new equal temperament. When I told " in our memlry we have only one place for ever ton" it must be interpreted- we have only one "image" for each interval. I explane-if we are in A major and A=440Hz, our "image" in our memory for a right fifth up is about 660Hz(not exactly with K1.5). Simply in our memory we feel this fifth in tune when is used only one K. The same for each other interval or other tonal center.Or other value for A! This "image" isn't absolute, but only relative. When we listen any melody and the divers intervals there respond to our memory "images", then we feel a good intonation, we feel that all there is in tune.Maybe for find this new equal 12ET I must beguin to try each of these 178 possible K? I am looking for software to try it easely and fast.

Comment: This question is unclear because it is not self contained but require previous knowledge from your others questions. Additionally, a lot of comments have been done on them to ask for clarification with no effect...

Comment: I have respond cleary, the rest is't my problem because there exist so many people who "adore" the  microtonal music(if it can be caled so) Also now I stoped to use the pseudo kajok and I am with my real name-Latchezar Dimitrov

Comment: @kajok This is not how this works. If people do not understand what you want it is first and most your problem (even if there are people who adore microtonal music), because it is you who is interested in getting answers. And you will probably not get answers from people if they do not understand the question.